# Turkey- flexibilty in e-Visa validity?

Tags: visas, turkey, canadian-citizens

I (Canadian citizen) have a Turkish e-Visa with a 6 month validity and a start date. Turns out I have a fairly long layover at Istanbul in advance of that date.

If I show up at Atatürk airport a week or two earlier than the start date, is there any chance they will adjust the start and end dates without having to shell out another $60 USD? The official e-Visa website basically says I am out of luck, but that may not apply when one shows up in person.

If you think there might be a chance, would I be able to find out before committing to leaving airside?

Followup: Only an entry stamp is put in the passport- your printed e-visa is the stamped document with the relevant dates, so there cannot be any flexibility. As stated in the comments, the Turkish Airlines hotel desk is outside customs (to the right as you walk out, against the inside wall). They did honour the hotel offer.

Comment: @Sephro which airline you are using and how long layover in Istanbul?

Comment: @AliAwan Turkish Airlines and 10 hours 10 minutes, changed (by them) from 9 hours 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately changes in Turkish Evisa are not allowed. From the beginning when we apply for an e visa, the website clearly mentions changes will not be permitted.
Also from Frequently ask questions confirms the same:

Source: [Evisa](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/)

[image]

Since you are traveling on Turkish Airlines and you have a layover for 10 hours and 10, you are can simply enjoy complementary hotel accommodation provided by Turkish airlines.

Source:[Turkish Airlines](http://www.turkishairlines.com/en-int/travel-information/frequently-asked-questions/travel-information/special-service-requests)

"A complimentary hotel accommodation (maximum 2 nights) will be provided to our valuable passengers when there are more than 10 hours (for economy cabin passengers) and 7 or more hours (for business cabin passengers) waiting during their international connecting flights due to Turkish Airlines’ schedule structure. The first and the connecting flights must be with Turkish Airlines. All passengers must hold a confirmed reservation for the first and the connecting flights."

Moreover if you plan to go outside from Ataturk airport, as a Canadian citizen you are still eligible to apply on arrival provided you meet all the required criterea in Istanbul airport. Also website [Ministry Of Foreign Affairs Turkey](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa) says

" Fees for e-Visas obtained via the e-Visa website (www.evisa.gov.tr) are lower than the fees for visas obtained upon arrival to Turkish airports."

Therfore there are 2 options available:

- 1 Either apply for a new evisa and pay another 60 USD
- 2 Or simply enjoy a complementy hotel stay at Attaturk airport

Comment: Thanks. It appears the complimentary hotel stay also requires a visa (from the link) "In the event where a visa is not granted, Turkish Airlines assumes no responsibility for providing complimentary hotel accommodation." It's still cheaper than the sole airside option (well over $200 CAD).

Comment: @Spehro I remember when my parents we traveling to USA 2 years ago, they got free hotel without any visa, I personally same wanted a hotel stay at Ataturk airport maybe 2 or 3 years ago and couldn't get it because of unavailability. Still I believe no visa is required for hotel stay, tomorrow morning will confirm with airline

Comment: Note that the free hotel is only available if there are no other options that would have given a shorter connection.  ie, if you could have had an earlier or later flight to reduce the connection time, then you do not get a hotel.

Comment: The hotel desk itself is located AFTER immigration, and there is no way to get to it without going through immigration, so you will absolutely need a visa.  There have been a (very few!) reports of business-class passengers getting a room in the airport hotel (which is air-side) by asking at the lounge, but this is extremely rare and most people that have tried have been rejected.